# no consigo que el el servidor almacene un nuevo usuario usando json y una consulta asincronica

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, phpmyadmin

estoy haciendo un proyecto de una pagina web en la que estoy tratando de implementar un formulario de registro, este se abre como un modal sobre la pagina web, por lo que estoy usando ajax para realizar  el envio de los datos a una pagina que procesa los datos y los envia al servidor  para luego almacenar la  respuesta y  devolverla en formato  json.

el  problema  es que cuando envio el  formulario la consola me  dice **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input** y si reviso el contenido del json esta vacio

[image: informacion recibida desde el json]

entiendo que  es un error por  como estoy armando la respuesta pero no consigo resolverlo

**registrar.js**

```
    document.getElementById("registrarUsuario").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      // Baja los datos desde el formulario
      // Obtén los valores de los campos del formulario de registro
      //los muestra por consola
      // Expresiones regulares para validar campos en el formulario de registro
      // Verifica si alguno de los campos está vacío
      // Valida el formato los campos con las expresión regular
      // Prepara una consulta asíncrona
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      // Prepara para enviar los datos a través de POST a la página establecida
      xhr.open("POST", "procesarInicioYRegistro.php");

      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

      // Una vez que se completó la solicitud XML
      xhr.onload = function () {
        // Verifica si se completó correctamente
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          // Baja los datos de la respuesta JSON
          let respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);  <-----------------
          console.log('El nombre de respuesta es:', respuesta);


          // Verifica el estado en la respuesta JSON y muestra su mensaje
          if (respuesta.status === "success") {
            console.log(respuesta.message);
          } else {
            alert(respuesta.message);
          }
        } else {
          // Imprime un mensaje de error en la consola si la solicitud no fue exitosa
          console.error("Error: ".xhr.status);
        }
      };

      // Envía la solicitud al servidor con los datos del formulario de registro
      xhr.send(new URLSearchParams(datosFormulario));
    });
```

la linea 77 es la  que  esta   marcada con una flecha en el  codigo

**procesarInicioYRegistro.php**

````
//incia una sesion para controlar header
session_start();
require("incluir/funciones.php");
require("incluir/array.php");
// realiza una conexión a la base de datos
require_once("base_de_dato/conexion_base.php");

//REGISTRAR
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && isset($_POST['registrarUsuario'])) {
    $nombre=(sanitizar_dato(limpiar_sql($_POST['nombreR']),$caracteres_con_tilde,$caracteres_sin_tilde ));
    $apellido=(sanitizar_dato(limpiar_sql($_POST['apellidoR']),$caracteres_con_tilde,$caracteres_sin_tilde ));
    $email=(sanitizar_email(limpiar_sql($_POST['emailR']),$caracteres_con_tilde,$caracteres_sin_tilde ));
    $usuario = (sanitizar_usuario(limpiar_sql($_POST['usuarioR'])));
    $contrasena =(sanitizar_contrasena(limpiar_sql( $_POST['contrasenaR'])));

    // Hashea la contraseña antes de almacenarla
    $contrasenaHash = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    // Utiliza una consulta preparada para verificar si el usuario ya existe
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT usuario_id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_usuario = ? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $usuario);

    // Ejecuta la consulta
    $stmt->execute();

    // Vincula el resultado a una variable
    $stmt->bind_result($id);

    // Verifica si se encontró una coincidencia
    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $respuesta = array("status"=>"error","message"=>"El usuario ya existe.");
            // Devuelve la respuesta en formato JSON
            echo json_encode($respuesta);
            exit();
    } else {
        // Si el usuario no existe, procede con la inserción del nuevo usuario
        $stmt->close();

        // Utiliza una nueva consulta preparada para insertar el nuevo usuario
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario_email, usuario_usuario, usuario_contrasena, usuario_nombre, usuario_apellido) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $email, $usuario, $contrasenaHash, $nombre, $apellido);
        // Ejecuta la consulta
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $respuesta = array("status"=>"success","message"=>"Registro exitoso.");
            //almacena el valor de nombre de usuario
            $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
        } else {
            $respuesta = array("status"=>"error","message"=>"Error al registrar el usuario:".$stmt->error);
        }
    }
    // Cierra la conexión y la consulta preparada
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    
    // Devuelve la respuesta en formato JSON
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
}

?>```
````

Comment: has intentado hacer console.log(xhr.responseText); para ver que es lo que esta devolviendo ????

Comment: hice una prueba con tu sugerencia y en la consola  figura un espacio vacío

Comment: entonces parece que la consulta no esta trayendo datos

Comment: gracias por responder, estuve  haciendo pruebas  y encontré que si **&& isset($_POST['registrarUsuario']** si comento esta  parte si  me reconoce los datos, alguna idea e que  podría ser ? ya revise que el formulario tiene esa id

Comment: verifica que hay dentro de esa variable... verifica si esta llegando vacia